# Badges for helpful flag streaks

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, helpful-flags, flagging-badges

Looking at the badges for the website, I feel that there is something missing: badges for helpful flag streaks. Here are some proposed values.

> Bronze Badge: 10 helpful flags in a row
>
> Silver Badge: 30 helpful flags in a row (could also be 50)
>
> Gold Badge: 100 helpful flags in a row (if that is too low, it can be 150 for 200)

They would help encourage people to raise helpful flags to earn badges.

Comment: Can you explain what the benefit of a flag streak is over a total helpful flag count is? Would this relate to post flags only or also to comment flags?

Comment: Note that this would encourage users to argue and fight back with mods even more than they already do when a flag is declined, potentially in cases where they even understand why it was declined, in the hopes of reviving the streak (or just due to being upset at losing a streak).

Comment: There are already [Deputy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/140/deputy) (80 helpful flags) and [Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal) (500 helpful flags). I don't see why it would be necessary to require that all the helpful flags are in a row.

Comment: Besides, if aged away flags would break the streak, that would be unfair because it's not the user's fault that their flag ages away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a concern about flag streaks that makes me feel like they're probably not in the best interest of encouraging users to flag whenever they feel like it's warranted.

While we definitely want to discourage random flagging or flagging that isn't thoroughly thought through, we also want to encourage users to flag things they feel need it. If we incentivize a flagging streak, that potentially reduces the likelihood of flagging in cases where the user is unsure whether the flag would be marked helpful.

Many of these borderline cases are harder to moderate but we definitely still need them brought to our attention (as diamond moderators). I already have users who dread having their flags declined because they want a high percentage of helpful flags; I don't want to depress flagging further by having users worried that their flags might be declined causing them to lose progress for a badge... and as a moderator, I don't want to have to weigh making someone start over at 0 for one declined flag that was borderline.

Additionally, if this included comment flags, which are the higher-volume flag content on the site I moderate, this would be even worse. We definitely need to see problematic comments but we may not necessarily agree that they need to be deleted right away, so declining may be necessary even if the comment is later deemed to be no longer needed.

There's also no way to change what the flag handling was after the fact, so if a flag was handled in error, we wouldn't be able to "fix" the streak. We definitely don't want to make errors in flag handling but to say that it doesn't happen would be to imply that the mods aren't human (which we **definitely are**... probably).

Comment: Why do you decline flags you seem to say are helpful? Is it because declining is the easiest / only way to dismiss the flag while keeping the comment (i.e. the system is lacking some necessary functionality)?

Comment: Yep. If you mark a comment flag as helpful, the comment is immediately deleted. So, if you want to leave the comment around, you have to find it and undelete it after handling the flag.